# Amend the function to reverse only third word

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Please bear in mind this question might seems duplicate but not asked before.

What should I use to amend the below function so it only reverse each third word in the string while staying in its current position, either slice or something else?

```
function reverseStringWords (sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return word.split('').reverse().join('');
  }).join(' ');
}
console.log(reverseStringWords("london glasgow manchester edinburgh oxford liverpool"));
```

Currently it is `nodnol wogsalg retsehcnam hgrubnide drofxo looprevil`

It should be `london glasgow retsehnam edinburgh oxford looprevil`

Comment: an hint: edit your third line to split and reverse and join only if the word counter you will implement is == to 3

Answer (score 3):

You can also use "Array.map" like below

Explanation - We need to figure out every third element which means if we have some number representing which position I am at while traversing array then we can check remainder by 3 of that position and if it's 0 it means its third, sixth, ninth... element

Now to find remainder we have `%` operator and that some number that will help us figure out which element position we are at is the `index`, second argument in `map` function but we would have to add 1 to `index` as in Javascript index starts with 0 not 1

So, logic to find every third element becomes `(i + 1) % 3 == 0`

```js
function reverseStringWords (sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').map((d, i) => 
            (i+1) % 3 == 0 
              ? [...d].reverse().join('') 
              : d)
}

console.log(reverseStringWords("london glasgow manchester edinburgh oxford liverpool"))
```

Comment: What does `[...d]` mean? Does `[...]` have a feature name?

Comment: 3 dots (...) is a `spread` operator introduced in ES6. In your case It's a short form for d.split('')

Comment: What means (i+1) % 3 == 0

Comment: i is the index of the element while looping. Now index starts with 0 for the first element, 1 for second element and so on.. Now to get every third element we can apply logic as - if remainder by 3 is 0 then it's third element.. and in javascript to find remainder we use '%' so (i +1) %3 when == 0 means it's third, sixth, ninth... element @Webappsdeva

Comment: @Webappsdeva `%` is the modulus operator. Basically, it tells whether the `(i+1)` item can be divided by 3, in that case (if it equals 0, it means it can be divided by 3, otherwise it can't)

Comment: @NitishNarang you should add an explanation to this code. It's great, of course, and clever and whatever, but without an explanation many persons may not understand some pieces of your code. You should add a brief explanation so that users won't get confused by reading that.

Comment: @briosheje Added Explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an index **i** to your map function, and check if is the one you want (starting from 0)

```
function reverseStringWords (sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').map(function(word,i) {
    return (i+1)%3==0  ? word.split('').reverse().join('') : word;
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: This function only reverse first third number not second third

Comment: yes, you said the third, not every 3, in this case you should check if is multiple. see the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a regular expression - capture the first two words and their spaces in one group, then capture the third word in another group, and return the first group concatenated with the second group reversed:

```js
const reverseStringWords = str => str.replace(
  /((?:\w+ ){2})(\w+)/g,
  (_, twowords, thirdword) => twowords + [...thirdword].reverse().join('')
);

console.log(reverseStringWords("london glasgow manchester edinburgh oxford liverpool"));
```